# Jest and ESM throwing errors with import fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am converting a node package into pure ESM. I have done the import changes to my files, added `"type":"module"` to `package.json` and also used `"exports":"./lib/index.js"`

When I run the test, I get the this common error:

```bash
    /x/__tests__/values.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import fs from 'fs'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've looked only, through many examples and Q&A, but almost all of them refers to changes with `ts-node` or `babel`. My package is quite simple, it does not use `babel` and it's plain javascript.

I am getting a bit stuck here, because I am nearly sure it's not a bug, but also I can't fix it.

I do not have any `transform` or `transformIgnorePatterns`. The test import section is

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import { values } from "../lib/index.js"

const expectedData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/testfiles/values.output.json"))
```

Jest is version `29.0.1`

Node is version `16.17.0`

Answer (score 0):

Jest does not understand ESM syntax out of the box.

> Jest ships with experimental support for ECMAScript Modules (ESM).

It is experimental and has many bugs.

You need to transpile your ESM syntax to CJS when running tests.

Babel is one option

1. Create `.babelrc` file with the following content

```json
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Install the plugin

```bash
npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
```

And that's it, now you can use ESM syntax in your tests.

If you want something else you can check the official [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started)

Comment: I know about this, but it does not solve.

Comment: You need to show your package json file too